# Array not returning pushed values from Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, axios

I declare an array outside of a function and push values inside the function. How do I get that array populated outside the function?

My code:

```
const higher_fnc = (query_name) => {
  return axios({
    url: GraphQL_Endpoint,
    method: "post",
    headers: headers,
    data: query_name,
  });
};

let myArr = [];

higher_fnc({
  query: query1,
  variables: {
    id: "1234567",
  },
}).then((d) => {
  for (const res of d.data) {
    const myObj = {};
    myObj["id"] = res.node.id;
    myObj["nm"] = res.node.title;
    myArr.push(myObj);
  }
});
console.log(myArr);
```

`res` returns:

```
"data": [
                {
                    "node": {
                        "id": "123",
                        "title": "Harry Potter"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "id": "456",
                        "title": "Percy Jackson"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "id": "890",
                        "title": "Game of Thrones"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "id": "678",
                        "title": "Lord of the Rings"
                    }
                }
]
```

I want `myArr` to return:

```
[
  {"id": "123", "nm": "Harry Potter"},
  {"id": "456", "nm": "Percy Jackson"},
  {"id": "890", "nm": "Game of Thrones"},
  {"id": "678", "nm": "Lord of the Rings"},
]
```

Currently, my code is just returning `[]`. How do I get `myArr` populated?